# SVG background-image repeat. Can I do that?

Tags: image, svg, repeat

I just want to know if **it's possible in svg format to generate an image or any type of object** that will accept background repeat like in `css` attribute.

Let's say I want to generate an iron bar from one `10px x 10px` image, and I have to repeat on `right for 100px, or on bottom for 100px.`

It's that possible?

If yes... how?

Comment: Do you mean inside of an svg, like e.g filling a path with that pattern? If so, you can use svg patterns (tutorial here: http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Patterns_and_Gradients). If you mean you want to tile an svg background-image, is http://philbit.com/svgpatterns what you want?

Comment: thank you for your answear. In first link I read about patterns, but none it was it an standalone jpg,gif or png image, and in second I don't get it how it's done and what It's done there since I don't see in the code link to the background-image.
What I want is to creat an iron bar that is 10x100 or 10x200 px using repeat or something similar from one 10x10 px image.

Comment: You can use an <image> element inside the <pattern> to reference a raster image that you want to tile. It probably will not look good if you scale it though.

Comment: but i want to repeat it, not to scale it...and since i put it inside a pattern will repeat the pattern... thank you for your answear....it was very usefull